# React js - Save previous value in Ant Design Steps

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design Steps for my form but I am having a problem on how to save the value of the previous input.

Here is my code whole code:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Steps } from 'antd';

const { Step } = Steps;

const steps = [
  {
    title: 'First',
    content: 'First-content',
  },
  {
    title: 'Second',
    content: 'Second-content',
  }
];

class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props) ;
    this.state = {
      current:  0
    }
  }

  next() {
    const current = this.state.current + 1;
    this.setState({ current });
  }

  prev() {
    const current = this.state.current - 1;
    this.setState({ current });
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { current } = this.state
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <div>
      <Steps current={current}>
      {steps.map(item => (
        <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />
      ))}
    </Steps>
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
      {current === 0 ? (
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator('username', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(
            <Input
              prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
              placeholder="Username"
            />,
          )}
        </Form.Item>
      ): ''}
      {current === 1 ? (
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
          })(
            <Input
              prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />,
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        ): ''}
      </Form>
          {current < steps.length - 1 && (
            <Button type="primary" onClick={() => this.next()}>
              Next
            </Button>
          )}
          {current === steps.length - 1 && (
            <Button type="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
              Done
            </Button>
          )}
          {current > 0 && (
            <Button style={{ marginLeft: 8 }} onClick={() => this.prev()}>
              Previous
            </Button>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What is happening is when I click next, the value of the previous input is gone. What I want to happen is when I click next the previous value will be save so when I click submit both of the values will be output in the console. The code comes from ant design and I used it for example

Answer (score 1):

You should consider storing the data in a state :

```js
 constructor (props) {
    super (props) ;
    this.state = {
      current:  0,
      firstInput: '',
      secondInput: '',
    }
  }
```

```js
 <Input
   prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />}
   placeholder="Username"
   onChange={(e) => this.setState({firstInput: e.target.value})}
 />,
```

Then, in your submit press, you will be able to access the values of `firstInput` and `secondInput` by doing `this.state.firstInput` & `this.state.secondInput`.